# Can I have a (bash) shell with expect running in the background?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, expect

I am trying to write an `expect` script that once started will watch my terminal and run a command every time that it finds a match.

Is this even possible with `expect`?  If so, would `expect_background` be the right thing to use?

EDIT: For clarity, I am trying to `expect` the output from my terminal, not the input...

Comment: I am really curious to know if there is a better tool to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this just with bash: redirect stdout to a `tee` process that can do something when your patterns are seen. `tee` is good because it also puts stdout on stdout.

```
exec 1> >(tee >(awk '/foobar/ {print "*** DING DING ***"}'))
```

This sends stdout to process substitution 1, `tee`, which copies it's stdin to both stdout and process substitution 2, an awk script that does something. You could put your code, or the path to a script, in the inner process substitution.

To demonstrate

```
$ echo this is foobar stuff
this is foobar stuff
$ exec 1> >(tee >(awk '/foobar/ {print "*** DING DING ***"}'))
$ date
Thu Mar 10 16:37:14 EST 2016
$ pwd
/home/jackman
$ echo this is foobar stuff
this is foobar stuff
*** DING DING ***
```

Comment: Great!  Now how do I stop it?

Comment: Easiest would be `exec 1> /dev/stdout`

Comment: Can this solution only find the matches if they are in the user input?

Comment: Or,before starting, copy stdout `exec 3>&1` then install the stdout catcher then shut it off with `exec 1>&3` and throw out the copy `exec 3>&-`

Comment: No, it's only looking at stdout. Can't test now but it should ding for `printf "%s%s\n" foo "bar"`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
#
# Adapted from autoexpect(1). Matches stuff from user.

if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
  send_user "Usage: $argv0 command \[cmd args...]\n"
  exit 64
}

match_max 100000
set userbuf ""

proc input {c} {
  global userbuf

  send -- $c
  append userbuf $c

  # if see this pattern in the input, execute command
  # NOTE may well muss up the terminal display, depending
  # on the output, etc.
  if {[regexp "echo.foo\r" $userbuf]} {
    system "uptime"
  # trim buffer between commands so not chewing up all the memory
  } elseif {[regexp "\r" $userbuf]} {
    set userbuf ""
  }
}

spawn -noecho $argv

interact {
  # match incoming characters, send to buffer builder (otherwise
  # if just "echo foo" here that input will vanish until expect
  # can run a command, or fails the match, which isn't nice.
  -re . { input $interact_out(0,string) }
  eof { return }
}
```

And the other way is simpler (but beware the shell echo).

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
#
# Also adapted from autoexpect(1).

if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
  send_user "Usage: $argv0 command \[cmd args...]\n"
  exit 64
}

match_max 100000

proc output {s} {
  send_user -raw -- $s

  # NOTE shells tend to echo commands as they are typed, which may
  # cause double-triggers depending on the expression being looked
  # for an what exactly is passed to this call from the echos.
  if {[regexp "foo" $s]} {
    system "uptime"
  }
}

spawn -noecho $argv

interact {
  -o -re .+ { output $interact_out(0,string) }
  eof { return }
}
```

Comment: See my edit... :)  Sorry for not making that clear... Interesting answer though.